# Stacking radio buttons in Bulma

Tags: html, radio-button, bulma

Is there a right way to stack radio buttons in Bulma?

Their [example](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/radio/) places each button on the same line:

```
<div class="control">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foobar">
    Foo
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foobar" checked>
    Bar
  </label>
</div>
```

[image]

I'm hoping to get something like this:

[image]

Would it be as straight forward as adding `<br>` tags, or does Bulma have a different better way for maintaining responsiveness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `<br>` works fine, it does not allow you to configure space between radio options flexible. For example, I can see a space between options in your example image.

In order to achieve that, I've added the following class to my SCSS:

```
.radio-list {
  .radio {
    display: block;

    & + .radio {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-top: .5em;
    }
  }
}
```

And now just add `radio-list` class to your control like this:

```
<div class="control radio-list">
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foobar">
    Foo
  </label>
  <label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="foobar" checked>
    Bar
  </label>
</div>
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: FooBar with space between options]

Answer (score 4):

A `<br>` tag between labels will work just fine.